# How to find timediff from jSON in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
with tasks_length as (
select 
metadata#>'{data,videoMetadata}' as time 
from table
), 

steptwo as (
select  
json_array_elements(time::json) elements    
from tasks_length
) 

select  
elements ->  'toTimestamp' as toTimestamp, 
elements ->  'fromTimestamp' as fromTimestamp
from steptwo
```

the feedback is:

[image]

How to find the time diff between fromtimestamp to totimestamp? I only need the mins/seconds as output.
because it's a json string i couldnt make it with totimestamp - fromtimestamp

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Comment: fwiw, there's some trade off for the DB server between network use and cpu/memory use, but you're likely better off returning the json, and having the client code parse out the values it needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the JSON fields as text and cast them to `timestamptz`.

```sql
select  
 (elements->>'toTimestamp')::timestamptz as toTimestamp, 
 (elements->>'fromTimestamp')::timestamptz as fromTimestamp,
 (elements->>'toTimestamp')::timestamptz - (elements->>'fromTimestamp')::timestamptz as timediff
from steptwo;
```

Comment: Thanks man!

another question

im getting this output:
0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 5.7 secs

how can i make this output show only secs for the timediff?

Comment: Use `extract('epoch' from the_timestamp_value)`